# check for a repeat value in xslt template

Tags: xml, templates, xslt-1.0, output

Given this xml sample document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Brown1>
   <Transaction>
    <Acct_Id>7801177</Acct_Id>
    <Acct_Nm>Name1</Acct_Nm>
    <Trans_Num>116902</Trans_Num>
    <Trans_Desc>Buy</Trans_Desc>
    <Trans_Result>Closed</Trans_Result>
   </Transaction> 
   <Transaction>
    <Acct_Id>7801177</Acct_Id>
    <Acct_Nm>Name1</Acct_Nm>
    <Trans_Num>116903</Trans_Num>
    <Trans_Desc>Sell</Trans_Desc>
    <Trans_Result>Closed</Trans_Result>
   </Transaction> 
   <Transaction>
    <Acct_Id>7801177</Acct_Id>
    <Acct_Nm>Name1</Acct_Nm>
    <Trans_Num>116904</Trans_Num>
    <Trans_Desc>Buy</Trans_Desc>
    <Trans_Result>Open</Trans_Result>
   </Transaction> 
   <Transaction>
    <Acct_Id>8692031</Acct_Id>
    <Acct_Nm>Name2</Acct_Nm>
    <Trans_Num>116932</Trans_Num>
    <Trans_Desc>Buy</Trans_Desc>
    <Trans_Result>Open</Trans_Result>
   </Transaction> 
    <Transaction>
    <Acct_Id>8692031</Acct_Id>
    <Acct_Nm>Name2</Acct_Nm>
    <Trans_Num>116999</Trans_Num>
    <Trans_Desc>Sell</Trans_Desc>
    <Trans_Result>Closed</Trans_Result>
   </Transaction> 
</Brown1>
```

What I want to get out is this

```
7801177 Name1

116902 Buy Closed
116903 Sell Closed
116904 Buy Open

8692031 Name2
116932 Buy Open
116999 Sell Closed
```

Basically only print acct & name once

Setting up templates kinda like this:

```
<xsl:template name="header">
  <xsl:value-of select="Acct_Id"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="Acct_Nm"/>

  <xsl:call-template name="report_data">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="report_data">
  <xsl:for-each select=".">
    <xsl:value-of select="Trans_Num"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="Trans_Desc"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="Trans_Result"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
```

This produces `Acct_Id` & `Acct_Nm` every time. How can I exclude them if they are the same when the next node processes?

I'm assuming in the header template, but I've been unable to get a solution.

It would seem to be a simple thing to do?..

Can I save the `Acct_Id` in the header template & compare it to the next `Acct_Id` & only print if different?

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kTransByAcct" match="Transaction" use="Acct_Id"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Transaction[generate-id()
              =generate-id(key('kTransByAcct',Acct_Id)[1])]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;',Acct_Id, ' ', Acct_Nm, '&#xA;')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kTransByAcct',Acct_Id)" mode="group"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="group">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#9;',Trans_Num,' ',Trans_Desc,' ',Trans_Result,'&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Brown1>
   <Transaction>
    <Acct_Id>7801177</Acct_Id>
    <Acct_Nm>Name1</Acct_Nm>
    <Trans_Num>116902</Trans_Num>
    <Trans_Desc>Buy</Trans_Desc>
    <Trans_Result>Closed</Trans_Result>
   </Transaction>
   <Transaction>
    <Acct_Id>7801177</Acct_Id>
    <Acct_Nm>Name1</Acct_Nm>
    <Trans_Num>116903</Trans_Num>
    <Trans_Desc>Sell</Trans_Desc>
    <Trans_Result>Closed</Trans_Result>
   </Transaction>
   <Transaction>
    <Acct_Id>7801177</Acct_Id>
    <Acct_Nm>Name1</Acct_Nm>
    <Trans_Num>116904</Trans_Num>
    <Trans_Desc>Buy</Trans_Desc>
    <Trans_Result>Open</Trans_Result>
   </Transaction>
   <Transaction>
    <Acct_Id>8692031</Acct_Id>
    <Acct_Nm>Name2</Acct_Nm>
    <Trans_Num>116932</Trans_Num>
    <Trans_Desc>Buy</Trans_Desc>
    <Trans_Result>Open</Trans_Result>
   </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
    <Acct_Id>8692031</Acct_Id>
    <Acct_Nm>Name2</Acct_Nm>
    <Trans_Num>116999</Trans_Num>
    <Trans_Desc>Sell</Trans_Desc>
    <Trans_Result>Closed</Trans_Result>
   </Transaction>
</Brown1>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
7801177 Name1
    116902 Buy Closed
    116903 Sell Closed
    116904 Buy Open

8692031 Name2
    116932 Buy Open
    116999 Sell Closed
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

**Update**:

The OP has dramatically requested a "non-key solution".

Beaware that a non-key solution has a quadratic time complexity -- O(N^2), while a key-based solution is close to O(1). The former can be many orders of magnitude slower than the latter.

**I strongly recommend and urge you *not* to use a non-key-based XSLT 1.0 solution for any practical purposes**.

Here is the requested non-key-based grouping solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Transaction[not(Acct_Id=preceding-sibling::*/Acct_Id)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;',Acct_Id, ' ', Acct_Nm, '&#xA;')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="group" select=
    ". | following-sibling::*[current()/Acct_Id = Acct_Id]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="group">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#9;',Trans_Num,' ',Trans_Desc,' ',Trans_Result,'&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
7801177 Name1
    116902 Buy Closed
    116903 Sell Closed
    116904 Buy Open

8692031 Name2
    116932 Buy Open
    116999 Sell Closed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can expand on this & apply it to a bigger project.However, I was wondering if there was any way to just modify the attached xls to make this work? Im still learning about using params to pass values to template and was wondering if it was possible to compare the acct_id of the current node to the acct_id of the previous node? Hope the question makes sense..thanks again

Comment: I did accept the answer..I was wondering if you read the other part of my response? I did find on the web about the grouping method above.This works with msxsl, but the processor used at work must not work with keys.SO, back to the original question..is there another way to do this?

Comment: @KenCatron, "Must not work with keys": Why??? The Muenchian grouping method is lightningly fast (close to O(1)), while the other methods that compare a value to that of all preceding (preceding-siblin) nodes, is O(N2). I have seen non-Muenchian" grouping that runs for 40 minutes and when Muenchian grouping is used on the same data, it runs in 2 seconds.

Comment: @KenCatron, Yes, there is a way, and you can find it in the update of this answer. More importantly, *never* use this technique in practice.

Comment: <xsl:template match="/Brown/Transaction">
    <xsl:call-template name="header">
       <xsl:with-param name="acctid" select="Account_Id"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="lastacctid" select="preceding-sibling::Transaction[1]/Account_Id"/>
 </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>                                                      <xsl:template name="header">
    <xsl:param name="acctid"/>
    <xsl:param name="lastacctid"/>

 <xsl:if test="position() = 2 or $acctid != $lastacctid">  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;',Acct_Id, ' ', Acct_Nm, '&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:if>

Comment: formatting messed up on that last response..short version..I just used the preceding-sibling

Comment: @KenCatron, Simple ??? with `xsl:call-temlate`, `xsl:param`, named template, `xsl:if` ??? This is an order of magnitude more complex than the solution in this answer. Also, has a lot more movig parts, each of which is quite error-prone -- and most important of all -- unnecessary.